# SO Careers Box Not Styled

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Today, the Stack Overflow Careers box is not being styled correctly when it appears (no special heading font, no background, etc):

[image: Careers box unstyled]

The "Jobs Near You" box looks file when it appears:

[image: Jobs Near You styled]

Comment: Looks fine here - Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m on Windows 7.

Comment: Seems this is an intermittent issue? [deleted post from earlier today] http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278787/careers-have-no-style

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yesterday we changed where the CSS for the Careers sidebar was being served from, and initially I had an incorrect domain name for our CDN. It *should* be fixed now, but please comment here if you see the issue pop back up again.

*EDIT*

Okay found the *real* culprit (and it was my own mistake, actually). We use [Less](http://lesscss.org/) for developing our style rules, and the client-side [less.js](https://github.com/less/less.js) for local testing. Part of our deploy process involves using hashes of the source files as cache breakers. There's a bit of javascript to detect whether the stylesheet should be `text/less` or `text/css`. Unfortunately that script was not stripping out the cache breaker query string, so the `<link>` element ended up with something like `type="text/css?v=6620c373eab1"`. Chrome will happily ignore the querystring, whereas Firefox and IE will see this as malformed and refuse to pull down the stylesheet.

The fix is going out now, and (hopefully) the sidebar should start showing up normally in FF and IE.

Comment: It's still broken for me. Firefox (34.0.5) and IE10 (10.0.9200.17148)

Comment: I'm seeing it too Ross. No particular error in Net panel, but definitely unstyled (no CSS) on the ads.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. It still feels like a stale cache issue, but I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: Nailed it. Will update answer.

Comment: Looking good for me now.